# Problems Creating a Gazebo Plugin

Tags: gazebo, tutorial, gazebo-plugin, plugin, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to simulate a tricycle robot using Gazebo that comes with ROS. I know how to create the simulation model that, however I've been unable to control the robot's movement. From what I've understood from the tutorials and forums, I need to create a plugin. To do so, I've tried to follow this tutorial:
http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro .
However, I've been unable to compile the simple_world_plugin.

Does anyone know of a better step by step tutorial regarding this issue?

Thank you for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36023/problems-creating-a-gazebo-plugin/) by [jplpinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2572/jplpinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-06-08**:
Are you on ROS electric or fuerte? The plugin API changed between versions, so that could explain your error.

**Comment by [jplpinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2572/jplpinto/) on 2012-06-08**:
I'm currently using diamondback. Which one should i use for this tutorial!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial you reference says it is for ROS Fuerte, which has an entirely new version of Gazebo (1.0).

You should probably upgrade to Fuerte, then try the tutorial again.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0